# Unsubscribing from Stack Exchange site and deleting profile?

Tags: support, status-completed

I am getting a flag that this post doesn't meet the site's quality standards, so I suspect that some key word like ArcMap is missing.

How do you unsubscribe from a Stack Exchange site and delete your profile?

I can't find out anything on this site nor on the main site.

I also am having trouble editing my profile on this site.

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267564/how-can-i-delete-a-stack-exchange-account-of-mine/267565#267565.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to address the facts, insofar as I know them, in a general way because many in the community may be interested in the information here.

---

I suspect the issue might (in part) concern my action yesterday to move an answer to the comment at [How to create backlink raster for Cost Distance tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60940/do-i-need-to-use-an-output-backlink-raster-in-cost-distance-tool#comment81407_60940).  The answer links to the appropriate help page and asserts the requested information can be found there.

This was a marginal call--and usually marginal situations should be addressed by leaving things as they stand--but ultimately I decided that the post ought to be changed to a comment because

1. It did not directly answer the question.  (A short while later, the OP themselves [said as much](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60940/do-i-need-to-use-an-output-backlink-raster-in-cost-distance-tool#comment81437_60940).)
2. It is primarily a link.  To avoid link rot, etc., we always ask that answers be self-contained, at least to the extent of summarizing the information in the links. At a minimum, it would require a moderator to add an "insufficient explanation" post notice.
3. Generally, replies of the form "go to the help/search page" ought to be comments.
4. The poster (Dan Patterson) is an experienced and respected community member, so I figured he would not need an explanation of the move.

I know nothing in particular about a "not meeting quality standards" message, but from experience do know that the system itself has (fairly mindless) algorithms that flag posts which are short or formatted in "interesting" ways; perhaps Dan received something automatically generated like that. The SE developers keep this algorithm a secret (to make it harder for spammers and trolls to circumvent it), but I suspect it may tend to flag answers consisting mainly of a link.

To diagnose the trouble in editing a profile we would need more information about what has been tried and what the system's response was.  As a moderator I can still, at present, access [the page for editing that profile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/edit/681), but to avoid any alarms or unintended damage, I hesitate to attempt any edits, even as a test.

---

I wish to add my voice to the many others, Dan, entreating you to stay with us, and for the same heartfelt reasons. A small thing like this is easily rectified and should be no reason for a major rupture. If there are bigger things behind this and they can be discussed in public then this meta site is a good place to do so; otherwise, we can talk offline.